# When moving, the movable div displays under another block in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

When moving, the movable div displays under another block. How to make this div appear on top of all the other blocks?

```
<div class="main-container">
    <div class="some-container"></div>
    <div class="group-container"></div>
</div>
```

```js
$('.group-container').draggable({
    containment: '.main-container'
});
```

I have this problem because class="some-container":

CSS

```
position: absolute;
right: 25px;
top: 89px;
width: 260px;
z-index: 1150;
height: 83%;
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: scroll;
```

How can I fix this, maybe cloning?

Added: 
I trying like this:

```
$('.group-container').draggable({
                containment: 'window',
                onDrag: myHelper,
                zIndex: 9999,
                stop: function(){
                    $(this).remove();
                }
            });

        // Element which created after start dragging
        function myHelper(event, ui){
            var newGroupBlock = $(this).clone().appendTo($(".main-container"));

            return newGroupBlock;
        }
```

But it's not working. The block that I should stand after dragging stay put where I dragged him, and he disappears ...

Comment: Change the z-index to be higher than your other blocks?

Comment: Probably `overflow-x: hidden;` is a problem. Try to remove this.

Comment: I trying but it's not working

Comment: I can't remove overflow-x. it is forbidden.

Comment: If you want to solve the issue, then try creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help us help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `start` and `stop` events of the draggable to set the `z-index` higher/lower. Try this:

```
$('.group-container').draggable({
    containment: '.main-container',
    start: function(e, ui) {
        ui.helper.css('z-index', 1200);
    },
    stop: function(e, ui) {
        ui.helper.css('z-index', 1100);
    }
});
```

Comment: No because it's a big project with big structure. I can write if you want some properties or someone else

Comment: @miriam 1) Don't add additional information below answers, instead edit your question and update it with the info. 2) don't dump code blocks in comments, it's very unreadable - do step1 instead.